# Seleniumbase maximize window

Tags: maximize-window, seleniumbase

I have been using Selenium for several years and am reasonably proficient. I have recently run into various bot/scraper detectors that have shut me out. It appears that seleniumbase has what it takes to avoid detection. However, i am unable to get the window (using chrome) to open and fill the entire screen - open maximized. In selenium this is relatively simple, but i have been unsuccessful in seleniumbase. I am running python and need to find the command(s) that will open the window in a maximized state. The documentation is quiet on this point and the code samples also do not seem to provide a model. I have used the settings file to get close, but it does not align itself properly in the corners. I know there is a way to do better.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window maximization is achieved in [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) after the browser is launched.

Use `driver.maximize_window()` with the SeleniumBase `Driver()` format. Example:

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(uc=True)
try:
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.open("https://seleniumbase.io/demo_page")
    driver.sleep(2)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: Worked first time. Thank you so much Michael. Been trying to track you down for a few other questions but i seem to be muddling through. Seleniumbase seems wonderful so far.

Comment: Awesome! Be sure to mark answers as Accepted if they answer your question.